# Android: trigger an event in Activity onCreate

Tags: java, android, event-handling, android-activity

My app has 2 activities which have no way to reference eachother; what I would like is when Activity B is created, an event is triggered in Activity A (I'm trying to "finish()" Activity A)

Is there some kind of event handler that I can create in Activity A to listen for such a thing?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you want? `ActivityA` will be in the background so what kind of an event do you want to trigger? Also, you may want to check out `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: I just want to notify ActivityA that ActivityB has been created. Currently, ActivityA has no knowledge of ActivityB

Comment: why would you want activityA to know that activityB is created ? may be there is a simpeler way

Comment: Wouldn't activity a already know that b is created because it just created it?

Comment: Activity A and B did not create eachother

Comment: I think you need to use one Activity that hosts multiple fragments. The fragments can "chat" to each other as much as you like.

Comment: by using startActivityForResult and then "chatting" via sending results back to the parent?

Comment: startActivityForResult not needed. Can communicate directly with each other or by using the host activity via callbacks.

Comment: I guess i don't understand what you mean by "fragments"

Comment: Google "Android Fragments"

Comment: ahh, I'm using API 8. I'll think of something, thanks for your help

Comment: Fragments are available for Api 8 by using the "Android Support Library".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one activity at a time can be active which makes it impossible for one activity to send a message directly to another in real time.

From your description, I think you need to use one Activity that hosts multiple fragments. The fragments can "chat" to each other as much as you like and both can be active at the same time.

Comment: I would add, "while the second `Activity` is still in the foreground"

Comment: Whilst the 2nd activy is in the foreground, the first is suspended.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. You could send a message back to the `Activity` but not while keeping the second `Activity` in the foreground which is what it sounds like he wants...that's all I was saying

Comment: If you want to send a result back to an activity From a 2nd activity, use StartActivityForResult

Comment: No problem, we were thinking the same thing, I just thought it needed some clarification was all

Comment: Correct, I want activity B to stay in the foreground while calling "finish()" on activity A

Comment: You cannot finish A whilst B is running because A is suspended. You would have to wait until A was resumed and then finish it.